# Android - display series of images using ImageView

Tags: android, image, timer, imageview, series

I try to display series of png images in a single ImageView using Timer (e.g. change pic every 1 sec.).

The app keep crashing, Here is my code, please help.
There is ImageView in the main.xml , for some reason i cant post the full xml file here. Anyway it just a standard main.xml with extra ImageView within the Linear Layout.

```
public class AniImgTest extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;
    public int i=0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       this.iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("","myDebug "+i);
                if(i<2)    
                    i++;
                else
                    i=0;

                switch(i){
                case 0:iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1); 
                    break;
                case 1:iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.a2); 
                    break;
                case 2:iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3); 
                    break;
                }

            }

    }, 0, 5000);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the stacktrace

Comment: Hi a380, Welcome to stackoverflow. You can add code, and xml content as well, but you need to mark it as code (see the options bar above the text edit box, or mark the code / xml and press ctrl+k)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is running on a different thread than main thread, so it can't change the GUI and causes crashes. Use [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to perform those tasks on the main thread.

One more thing (which is not related, but...), instead of:

```
if(i<2)  
    i++;
else
    i=0;
switch(i){
```

you can write:

```
switch(++i % 3){
```

Answer (score 0):

use this block of code to change UI components

```
     AniImgTest.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                // change your image here.
            }
        });
```